# How to fix "RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback" when using tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient?

Tags: python, tornado

I use `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient` in my tornado web application' headler.

Here is my code

```py
class CustomTornadoHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def set_default_headers(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        self.set_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE, PUT')

    def initialize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.db_session = db_session()

    def on_finish(self):
        db_session.remove()


class AdminUploadAlignerParagraphTaskHandler(CustomTornadoHandler):

    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()

    @run_on_executor
    def post(self):

        async def f():
            http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
            try:
                response = await http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com")
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error: %s" % e)
            else:
                logging.info(response.body)
        ...
        self.write("")
        f()
```

I get the example in https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html.
But it doesn't work:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'AdminUploadAlignerParagraphTaskHandler.post.<locals>.f' was never awaited
  f()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

What should I do?

Comment: That's not an error, it's a warning. It looks like some asyncio task was created but not awaited using the await keyword. Does your program still do what it's supposed to be doing? If so, you can probably ignore the warning.

Comment: Hi,@AlexWeavers.But it seems like that ```logging.info(response.body)``` doesn't execute

Comment: Does your script start and stop running very quickly?

Comment: Hi,@AlexWeavers.Yes,it's very quickly since it's a web interface

Comment: My guess is that it's sending the request, but the script completes before the request gets back and exits, raising this warning. HTTP requests generally take about 50ms to complete. Does that sound possible?

Comment: To get the traceback: "[set] the PYTHONTRACEMALLOC environment variable to 1, or [use] -X tracemalloc command line option." Read [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tracemalloc.html) for more details. (although in this particular case it's already obvious)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `f()` is a coroutine, and you're just calling it without awaiting. You'll need to use `await f()` to call it. For that to work, you'll also need to convert the `post` method to a coroutine.

---

You're unnecessarily complicating the `post` method. I don't see why you're running it on a separate thread.

Here's how I'd rewrite it:

```
# no need to run on separate thread
async def post():
    http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()

    try:
        response = await http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: %s" % e)
    else:
        logging.info(response.body)

    ...

    self.write("")
```